# c++ Чтение вектора из файла

Tags: c++, вектор, файловый-ввод-вывод

В текстовом файле записаны построчно векторы 0 и 1: (пример, 3 вектора)
00111001
10100100
10011010

Не получается прочитать даже первый вектор - долгая сборка, видимо память грузится.
Пробую читать символы до конца строки \n, код ниже.

```
vector <bool> vec;
if (vec_file.is_open()) 
    {
        while (char ch = vec_file.get() != '\n')
        {
            vec_file.seekg(-1); // if char is not \n then go back and read as a boolean

            bool temp = vec_file.get();
            vec.push_back(temp);    //add vector's element

        }
    }
    vec_file.close();
    print_vec(vec); //функция вывода вектора сама по себе работает
```

Выходит что-то очень-очень долгое.
Подскажите, чем я так память огорчаю?..

Comment: Эмм вы считываете `ch`, в самом цикле просите пользователя ввести `bool` потом закидываете это в `vec`, а `ch` то зачем? Не понятно что ваш код делает.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Спасибо за ответ!
Исправила часть с вводом, все равно не работает

'''
vector <bool> vec;

 //test reading
 if (vec_file.is_open()) 
 {
  while (char ch = vec_file.get() != '\n')
  {
   vec_file.seekg(-1); // if char is not \n then go back and read as a boolean

   bool temp = vec_file.get();
   
   vec.push_back(temp); //add vector's element

  }
 }
 vec_file.close();
 print_vec(vec);

'''
Предполагалось вообще, что сначала прочитается символ (конец строки или нет?), а если не конец строки, то прочитается снова, но как bool - элемент массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `char ch = vec_file.get() != '\n'` этой строчкой вы каждую итерацию получаете символ из файла и сравниваете его с `\n` а результат сравнения заносите в `ch` и получается, что пока вы не дошли до `\n` у вас `ch` будет = 1.

   То что вы хотели реализовать выглядит примерно таким образом:

   ```
   char ch;
   while ((ch = vec_file.get()) != '\n')
   ```

   Вы сначала присваиваете `ch` считанный символ из файла, а потом уже проверяете его с `\n`.
2. Далее внутри цикла я вообще не понял, вашу реализацию.

   Вы уже прочитали символ в `ch` все что вам остается это добавить его в `vec` как `bool`. Но т.к. код `'0'` и `'1'` это `48` и `49` соответственное (см. [таблица ascii](http://www.asciitable.com)), то написав такую строчку:

   ```
   bool temp = ch;
   ```

   `temp` всегда будет равна единице, т.к. `true` это все, что не `0`. В нашем случае это `48` и `49`.
   Так что вам нужно получить из **символов** `'0'` и `'1'` коды `0` и `1` соответственно.

   Чтобы получить из символа `'0'` с кодом `48` код `0` нужно, логично, отнять `48` или `'0'` и уже его добавлять в вектор, то есть:

   ```
   //vec.push_back(ch - 48); Равносильно строчке ниже
   vec.push_back(ch - '0'); //Проще для понимания
   ```

Чтобы вы не запутались, вот пример цикла, которые считывает символы до `\n` занося `0` и `1` в вектор:

```
char ch;
while ((ch = vec_file.get()) != '\n') {
    vec.push_back(ch - '0');
}
```

Так же вы должны учитывать, что и последняя строчка должна быть окончена `\n` иначе произойдет бесконечный цикл.